# Laravel Image File path not working on server

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I have my laravel application hosted on a server in the root directory as follow:

```
./Project
```

I have my images folder inside public folder of the project which reside in public_html with the path as following:

```
./public_html/project/images
```

How can i upload image on this path from my controller and also how to retrieve data from there?
what i have tried so far for uploading is:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/project/images
```

but it didn't worked for me. can i have a little help on how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

For inserting data, you can use:

```
$request->file('image')->store('your-path');
```

Example:

```
$name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
$path = $request->file('image')->store('public/store/images');
$save = new Photo;
$save->name = $name;
$save->path = $path;
$save->save();
```

And for retrieving an image:

```
$getImage = {{asset('images/your-image-name')}}
```

Comment: it doesn't works for me as i have mentioned that my application is stored inside the root folder, only the public folder is inisde the public_html which is named as project